# What does soulbound mean?

Tags: terminology, realm-of-the-mad-god

Does it mean if I die I get to keep the item? I have no idea what it means, and anytime I ask in chat, everyone tries to trade for some reason.

So I found a Large Jester Cloth or something that was soulbound, but I have no idea what Soulbound means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soulbound is the system that RotMG uses for certain rare drops, usually from the most powerful mobs in the game.  In RotMG, it simply means that **only the person it dropped for can loot it.**  That means, if you saw it on the ground, it was yours - no one else could pick it up.  Only some of the best items in the game are protected that way, so it's probably pretty valuable.

I don't play enough RotMG to know what that exact item does, sorry.  After being looted, soulbound doesn't actually do anything else that I know of - you can trade it or drop it, or lose it to death like any other item.  It just keeps the soulbound "tag" to remind you that it was soulbound on drop.

Answer (score 5):

Soulbound items and soulbound loot are different in RotMG. In this case you have a soulbound item. Soulbound items will be lost on death. Soulbound items cannot be given to other players by dropping it or trading it.

Soulbound loot just means purple/cyan/white bags, which cannot be accessed by other players, unlike brown/pink bags. If you drop a soulbound item on the ground, it will appear in a purple bag and only you will be able to see it.

Soulbound damage is also term used to describe the amount of damage you need to deal to a boss in order to have a chance to get high tier items/potions.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 types of soulbound.

1. An item that has soulbound written on it. You cant trade it to other people or if you drop it into a bag others wont be able to pick it up.
2. soulbound damage. The more soulbound damage you did to a certain boss or monster the greater your chance is to get a soulbound item.

Comment: If you want to make changes, please update your existing answer rather that posting a new one

Comment: No i'm writing 2 answers

Answer (score -3):

Soulbound is how much damage you did to a said enemy. The more damage you did the greater the chance that you will get stuff. Not all enemies can drop soulbound items. Only higher level enemies can. SOulbound bags are colored purple, cyan, orange or white.