# How does soulbound work?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

How do I know if I will get a white bag or something soulbound from a boss? Is it a set amount of damage you have to do to the enemy, or does it vary with the amount of players in a said realm or dungeon?
I've gotten white bags from Deadwater Docks before, but at some point I did more damage but didn't get a white bag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does soulbound mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192014/what-does-soulbound-mean)

Comment: This is asking if soulbound is always the same these are different

Answer (score 1):

This gets asked a lot.

It is not something published by DECA and it is more of a speculation and a lot of tests from different players but it **looks to be related to the damage done and number of players in most cases**

I think the most comprehensive answer (list of theories) you can find is here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/RotMG/comments/46or1f/how_does_the_loot_system_work/

inside ROTMGBotzilla post